# What is this error in Python tabula module?

Tags: python, pandas, tabula

I keep getting this error. I am working on -

Mac Sierra 10.8

Python 3.6.2

tabula 1.0.5

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Sam/Desktop/mitch test/test.py", line 22, in <module>
    tabula.convert_into(root.fileName, "_ExportedPDF-" + date_time + ".csv", output_format="csv", pages="all")
AttributeError: module 'tabula' has no attribute 'convert_into'
```

This is my code that is giving me an error.

```
tabula.convert_into(root.fileName, "_ExportedPDF-" + date_time + ".csv", output_format="csv", pages="all")
```

---

UPDATE:

When I try to do `from tabula import wrapper` I get th error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'wrapper'
```

---

UPDATE:

Fixed comment as per @L. Alvarez

Getting following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Sam/Desktop/mitch test/test.py", line 22, in <module>
    tabula.convert_into(root.fileName, "_ExportedPDF-" + date_time + ".csv", output_format="csv", pages="all")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tabula/wrapper.py", line 140, in convert_into
    subprocess.check_output(args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 336, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout 
File"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 418, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['java', '-jar', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tabula/tabula-0.9.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar', '--pages', 'all', '--guess', '--format', 'CSV', '--outfile', '_ExportedPDF-Jul 26 2017.csv', '/Users/Sam/Desktop/mitch test/security_by_curr_risk_ldw.pdf']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suspect you did `pip install tabula`, which installed a `tabula` library that has a version 1.0.5. Here's [the github repo](https://github.com/ronniedada/tabula). It does not have a convert_into function

But you actually meant to install [this tabula](https://github.com/chezou/tabula-py), whose last version is 0.9.0

You should `pip uninstall tabula` and `pip3 install tabula-py`

Comment: tabula-py is just a wrapper around [tabula-java](https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula-java). Which means python is calling some Java code under the sheets.  And the vague error you just got means something went wrong at the Java level. It could be anything. I recommend you at least do `java -version' and validate that your Java is version 7 or 8, which appear to be the required versions for tabula

Comment: You could try calling the Java code directly afterward, hopefully the error you get calling the Java code directly is less vague

Comment: I'm still getting this error even with Java installed and no tabula package installed...

Answer (score 2):

## CalledProcessError: Command '['java', '-jar', '/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tabula/tabula-1.0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar', '--pages', '1', '--guess',]' returned non-zero exit status 1

If you are getting above error then it means you have to install java-jre and java-jdk

```
sudo apt-get install default-jre

sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

you can follow the steps here if the above installation dosent work
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-get-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 0):

just do these 2 steps :

1. pip uninstall tabula
2. pip3 install tabula-py
   execute these in your command prompt

and your error will be solved.